# how to calculate recursiv value in crystal report in detail section?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

My example:

```
header
s0 = 200;

detaile1:
s1 = s0 + x;
detail2:
s2 = s1 + x;
detail3:
s3 = s2 + x;
```

I need to transfer the result from one detail to another.
Is this possible in crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Running Total and place it in the Detail section